# append() and $(this).addClass() method in jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am refactoring former JavaScript code into jQuery. I use  the `append()` and `$(this).addClass()` methods, but it seems they don't work. I don't know what the problem is.

The JavaScript code is about creating a puzzle game (15 puzzles). I am trying to add an element into an HTML file in the jQuery way.

```
var tile = function(i, j) {
    this.seq = i * 4 + j + 1;
    this.row = i + 1;
    this.column = j + 1;
    if (i * 4 + j != 15) {
        $(this).addClass("block puzzle row" + this.row + " column" + this.column);
        var xPosition = -j * 88;
        var yPosition = -i * 88;
        $(this).css("backgroundPosition", xPosition + "px " + yPosition + "px");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("block row" + this.row + " column" + this.column);
        $(this).attr('id', "blank");
    }
}

function Init() {
    var node = $("#imgContent");  //  imgContent is a div
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var t = new tile(i, j);
            node.append(t);
        }
    }
   //  Generate the original picture before the start
   Judge.isStart = false;
}
```

How do I use these jQuery methods properly?

Comment: your function tile is didn't return anything ?

Comment: state what are you trying to achieve on this code

Comment: What is `this` within your `tile` function? It doesn't look like a DOM object, which jQuery should manipulate with.

Comment: @SudharsanS It is a constructor function, which is called with `new`. It shouldn't return anything.

Comment: @NicholasLiao Your code is OK, except for jQuery manipulation. `$(this)` - here `this` is not an element, it is `tile` object. You need to pass DOM element to jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using $(this) incorrectly. 
When the tile() function is called with new, it is instantiated as an object and 'this' becomes a reference to that object.  In doing so, you can assign values to its internal state using 'this.' syntax.

jQuery is primarily designed to manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM).  Usually you'll pass a selector into jQuery which finds the matching HTMLElements from the document and returns them for manipulation.   $(this) within the context of tile is passing the this reference which jQuery just returns back to you.

Important part here is that $(this) represents the tile object and not actually an element from the document.  The .css .addClass and .append functions aren't applicable, as they work on elements.  You need to pass a selector or an element into jQuery to use them.

A solution is to create an element within tile that can be appended to the document.

https://jsfiddle.net/hxqduoef/2/

```
var tile = function(i, j) {
    this.seq = i * 4 + j + 1;
    this.row = i + 1;
    this.column = j + 1;

    // $("<div></div>") creates a new div element wrapped in the jQuery object, it isn't part of the document until it gets appended.   saving to this allows further manipulations within this constructor.
    this.element = $("<div>Tile at "+ i +" "+ j +"</div>");

    if (i * 4 + j != 15) {
        this.element.addClass("block puzzle row" + this.row + " column" + this.column);
        var xPosition = -j * 88;
        var yPosition = -i * 88;
        this.element.css("backgroundPosition", xPosition + "px " + yPosition + "px");
    } else {
        this.element.addClass("block row" + this.row + " column" + this.column);
        this.element.attr('id', "blank");
    }

}

function Init() {
    var node = $("#imgContent");  //  imgContent is a div
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var t = new tile(i, j);
            node.append(t.element);
        }
    }
   //  Generate the original picture before the start
   // Judge.isStart = false;
}
```

This adds the "this.element" property, sets it as a new DIV element and references it instead of the t in the node.append(t.element) statement.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**`$(this)`** `is actually defined by the invoker of the function, while explicit variables remain intact inside the function declaration block known as the enclosure.`

What's happening in your function is `tile(i,j)`, is being called explicitly, this means context or the "this" of the function is the `window object`.Being specific to your question, `this` is bound to the global object, that is `window`.

For example, consider the following function,

```
function myFunc(){
}
```

and,

```
var myObj= { myFunc: myFunc};
```

If you call using `myObj.myFunc()`; then `this` is bound to `myObj`.

If you call `myFunc()` directly, such as, `myFunc();`,
then `this` is bound to the global object, that is `window`.

Hence, calling a function without a following parent object will generally get you the `global object` which in most browsers means the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

context of `this` is getting changed, keep `this` to a variable, then use that variable.

```
var $this = this;
var tile = function(i, j) {
$this.// your code
}
```